# Delete my application programmatically (Android)

Tags: android, uninstallation

I want to uninstall my application on button click. For this I am using following code.

```
Uri packageURI = Uri.parse("package:"+packageName);
Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageURI);
startActivity(uninstallIntent);
```

It gives me result, but I want to delete directly without click on "Ok" button of  dialog with message "This application will be Uninstalled".

I just want uninstalling application directly.

Comment: You need to have root permission to do that.

Comment: This sort of stuff is reserved for system applications for good reasons - so you're stuck with rooting your device.

Comment: I think you should step back and think about why you would want to do this anyway. Why would you need to override the standard method for removing an application?

Comment: @xDragonZ do you have any idea how to get root permission? it's about rooting of device can you guide me how to code for rooted device.

Comment: @amity Just exec the command `su` and within that Process you have root priviliges:

`Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");`
See this [blog](http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/01/android-requesting-root-access-in-your-app/) post for full example.

Comment: @kcoppock I want to do that on an instance when device get stolen and I dont want my application to be on the device. At that time I want my application to uninstall.

Answer (score 11):

Uninstalling without user confirmation is not allowed to 3rd party applications.

As xDragonZ points out, a root process can crudely do this by literally removing the directory and leaving the package manager to deal with the loss, but that's not a very widely deployable solution, since AFAIK no devices ship with that capability for apps to run their own root helper process - that's a risky aftermarket modification.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is possible to uninstall a package in Android. Moreover you can also skip asking user to press OK button on uninstall screen. You can do it by using Accessibility service in Android.

```
public class MyAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService {
    private static final String TAG = MyAccessibilityService.class
            .getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        Log.i(TAG, "ACC::onAccessibilityEvent: " + event.getEventType());

        //TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED == 32
        if (AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED == event
                .getEventType()) {
            AccessibilityNodeInfo nodeInfo = event.getSource();
            Log.i(TAG, "ACC::onAccessibilityEvent: nodeInfo=" + nodeInfo);
            if (nodeInfo == null) {
                return;
            }

            List<AccessibilityNodeInfo> list = nodeInfo
                    .findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId("com.android.settings:id/left_button");
            for (AccessibilityNodeInfo node : list) {
                Log.i(TAG, "ACC::onAccessibilityEvent: left_button " + node);
                node.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK);
            }

            list = nodeInfo
                    .findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId("android:id/button1");
            for (AccessibilityNodeInfo node : list) {
                Log.i(TAG, "ACC::onAccessibilityEvent: button1 " + node);
                node.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK);
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected() {
        Log.i(TAG, "ACC::onServiceConnected: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this is only useful for apps that already use an Accessibility service. Otherwise it's of no use since prompting a user to enable an accessibility service inconveniences them more than just pressing "Ok" on an uninstall dialog.

Answer (score 1):

You should first look into the Android native [PackageInstaller](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInstaller.html). I would recommendating you to update all the code you use.

---

Next step is to inspect [PackageInstaller](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInstaller.html) which is an normal class. You will find that `uninstall` function there. The bad news is that this needs `Manifest.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES` permission and its only granted to system apps. This means that this is not available directly to other developers. But we can access it using device owner permission.

---

This requires:

- Android 6.0 or newer
- Device owner permission to uninstall the package

Generally the `DELETE_PACKAGES` permission says:

> Allows an application to delete packages.
>
> Not for use by third-party applications.

Once your app gets the device owner permission, you can uninstall an package like this:

```
String appPackage = "com.your.app.package";
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
getApplicationContext().getClass()); //getActivity() is undefined!
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivity(), 0, intent, 0);
PackageInstaller mPackageInstaller = 
getActivity().getPackageManager().getPackageInstaller();
mPackageInstaller.uninstall(appPackage, sender.getIntentSender());
```

The code used available here:

[PackageInstaller "Silent install and uninstall of apps by Device Owner” - Android M Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32473158/packageinstaller-silent-install-and-uninstall-of-apps-by-device-owner-androi/37251196#37251196)