# Android 9 Intent.ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE not working

Tags: android, android-intent

On android pie, I want to call the package manager to uninstall my own app. Here is what I am trying:

```
val uri = Uri.parse("package:$packageName")
val uIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE, uri)
startActivity(uIntent)
```

Oddly this is not working. Nothing is being shown in the logcat as well.

I have also tried ACTION_DELETE

```
val uri = Uri.parse("package:$packageName")
val uIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, uri)
startActivity(uIntent)
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong. This seems a pretty straightforward job. Am I missing any permission or something I need to declare in manifest?
Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was missing manifest permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_DELETE_PACKAGES"/>
```

This is probably required for Android 6.0 and above. The code in the question now works perfectly. Tested on Android 9 and Android 10.

Comment: I also had the experience that starting the intent didn't work for me with the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag (`intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`)

Comment: It works on Android 12. This method deprecated but there is no alternative yet.

Answer (score -1):

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE);
 intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:com.example.myapplication"));
 startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Well, I tried ACTION_DELETE as well. Let me update the question.

Comment: hmm after doing some Google research, it looks like this ability is not available to 3rd party applications, but there may be some workarounds. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483493/delete-my-application-programmatically-android

Comment: Ok. But I do want to show the confirmation. The question you linked to asks for a way to directly uninstall the app without any confirmation.