# Is it possible to force uninstall my app?

Tags: android, ios

I have business apps, both iOS and Android, and my business is discontinuing.

Ideally, I would like to have my apps removed from the app store and uninstalled all devices they're installed. Is that possible?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483493/delete-my-application-programmatically-android

Comment: No you can't .. However on discontinuing you probably stop serving the API request which will cause Error in mobile application . Then people probably uninstall it themselves. On other hand if you have error handling mechanism implemented in current build you can show a Non closable Banner with Info about discontinuing and uninstalling.

Answer (score 0):

You can delist your application in both stores so new users can not find / install the application, but I'm unaware of any way in which you force uninstall the application from existing devices.   If you are discontinuing a service that has been paid for, for subscriptions you'll need to sort out pro-rota refunds for all affected customers too (if you're planning on discontinuing the service).  You can withdraw the paid option in the store, so no one else can sign up, and existing users won't renew at the end of their subscription period.